# create output line layer between two overlapping line layers

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I have two street layers in QGIS. My main aim is to create an output layer of the overlapping streets (extract the overlapping portions from the red streets via blue intersect layer). The file size of the red streets is too large, therefore I want to select just the streets, which are within the map extent for my intersection.  The output should also contain the attribut information of the red streets.

I copied a code in which I could intersect both layers, but I could not fix the selection within the map extent, and I could not create an output layer with the attribut information. Below you can see my code and an image:

```
registry = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance();
blue_street = "blue_streets";
red_street = "red_streets";

route_blue = registry.mapLayersByName( blue_street ) [0];
streets_red = registry.mapLayersByName( red_street ) [0];
extent = iface.mapCanvas().extent()

selections= []
for f in route_blue.getFeatures():
    for a in streets_red.getFeatures():
        if a.geometry().intersects(f.geometry()):
            intersection = a.geometry().intersection(f.geometry())
            print intersection.exportToWkt()
            selections.append( f.id() )
        break
```

[image]